# Sitecore Powershell script to find items that break inheritance

Tags: powershell-extensions

I need to write a Powershell script to find items that refer to a specific composite component and break inheritance for presentation. If I go to the Navigation Tab in the Content Editor and click Links I get a list of these items but I want to filter out the ones that are marked as [Inherited].

Here's my script:

```
$props = @{
   InfoTitle = "Referrers"
    InfoDescription = "Lists all items that are using this item"
    PageSize = 25
}

function Get-ItemReferrers {
    $item = Get-Item -Path "/sitecore/content/Shared/Composite components/Header"
    $linkDb = [Sitecore.Globals]::LinkDatabase
    $links = $linkDb.GetReferrers($item)
    foreach($link in $links){
        $linkedItem = Get-Item -Path master:\ -ID $link.SourceItemID
        $linkedItem
    }
}

$items = Get-ItemReferrers
$items | Show-ListView @props -Property @{Label="Name"; Expression={$_.DisplayName} },
        @{Label="Path"; Expression={$_.ItemPath} },
        @{Label="Inheritance"; Expression={$_."__Renderings"} },
        @{Label="Updated"; Expression={$_.__Updated} },
        @{Label="Updated by"; Expression={$_."__Updated by"} },
        @{Label="Created"; Expression={$_.__Created} },
        @{Label="Created by"; Expression={$_."__Created by"} }

Close-Window
```

I have tried a number of fields for the Inheritance field but I don't think that is stored in a field. How do I tell if the item does not inherit presentation from standard values?

Comment: Did the answer solve your issue @HoffsTech?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I use the built-in command `Get-ItemReferrer` I do not see inherited items.

Avoid writing your own function and use the OOTB one.

```powershell
# Get the Sample Inner Sublayout item
$item = Get-Item "master:" -ID "{CE4ADCFB-7990-4980-83FB-A00C1E3673DB}"
Get-ItemReferrer -Item $item
```

[image: Output]

[image: Referrers]