# Powershell get all items that use a template

Tags: powershell-extensions

The title pretty much says it all - I've looked at the docs but I just keep finding `Get-Item` and `Get-ItemTempate`.

Lets say I have a template with id 123456, I want to get all items that are using this template. How would I do that?

Comment: How would you do that in C#?

Comment: Something like `allItems.Where(p => p.TemplateIdList.Contains("123456"));` Let me see if I can powershell that! - Disclaimer - New to Sitecore so I don't know what exists and what doesn't...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should do it for you.

```
$defaultPath = "/sitecore/content"
[Sitecore.Data.ID]$articleId = "{03360FC1-B4C0-4770-9E1D-79E8317B74DD}"

$articles = Find-Item -Index sitecore_master_index `
   -Where 'TemplateId = @0 and Path.StartsWith(@1)' `
   -WhereValues $articleId, $defaultPath | Initialize-Item
```

Another way using template name and Criteria.

```
$articles = Find-Item `
   -Index sitecore_master_index `
   -Criteria @{Filter = "Equals"; Field = "_templatename"; Value = "Article"},
   @{Filter = "Equals"; Field = "_language"; Value = "en"},
   @{Filter = "StartsWith"; Field = "_fullpath"; Value = "/sitecore/content" }
```

Comment: If I do a `Write-Host $_.FullPath` on everything in `$articles`, then I get quite a log of duplicates. Any idea why this would happen?

Comment: (using the first example btw)

Comment: multiple languages? This is is reading directly from the index, so we have to know why there are multiple items in your index.

Comment: Ah potentially - I'll investigate if that is the case. Thanks

Answer (score 19):

There is a report included with SPE called *Items with Template* that can provide you with this information. This report scans a tree and checks for inheritance at any level. Slow because it has to look at every item. Incomplete because it only looks at the tree specified.

[image: Sample Report Dialog]

I would recommend you use the `Get-ItemReferrer` command. This is based on the Link Database and should be extremely fast; items that in no way are related are never requested. **Be sure the Link Db is up-to-date before running**.

A similar question was asked [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/7339/sitecore-powershell-script-to-find-items-that-break-inheritance/7340#7340).

#### Find related items

**Example:** The following returns all items referring to a given template.

```powershell
$sampleItemTemplateId = "{76036F5E-CBCE-46D1-AF0A-4143F9B557AA}"
$sampleItemTemplateItem = Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID $sampleItemTemplateId

Get-ItemReferrer -Item $sampleItemTemplateItem
```

As you can see below, all referrers are returned. You can then filter out with `Where-Object` if you want to exclude content, media, templates, etc.

[image]

#### Find related items at any level of inheritance

**Example:** The following returns all items referring to a given template that inherit that template. Demonstrates the use of the [trampoline technique](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/10300/95) to reduce call depth. There are checks to ensure that the item exists and no duplicates are returned.

```powershell
function Get-ItemBasedOnTemplate {
    param(
        [string]$TemplateId
    )

    $queue = New-Object System.Collections.Queue
    $processedLookup = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]
    if(-not(Test-Path -Path "master:$($TemplateId)")) { return }
    $processedLookup.Add($TemplateId) > $null  
    Get-ItemReferrer -Id $TemplateId -ItemLink | 
        Where-Object { $_.SourceItemID } | 
        ForEach-Object { $queue.Enqueue($_.SourceItemID) }

    $database = Get-Database -Name "master"
    while($queue.Count -and ($referrerId = $queue.Dequeue())) {
        if($processedLookup.Contains($referrerId)) { continue }
        $processedLookup.Add($referrerId) > $null
        $referrer = $database.GetItem($referrerId)
        if(!$referrer) { continue }
        if($referrer.Paths.FullPath.StartsWith("/sitecore/templates")) { 
            if($referrer.Name -eq "__Standard values") { continue }
            foreach($referrerItemLink in Get-ItemReferrer -Id $referrerId -ItemLink | Where-Object { $_.SourceItemID }) {
                $queue.Enqueue($referrerItemLink.SourceItemID)
            }
            $itemTemplate = [Sitecore.Data.Managers.TemplateManager]::GetTemplate($referrerId, $database)
        } else {
            $itemTemplate = [Sitecore.Data.Managers.TemplateManager]::GetTemplate($referrer)
        }
        
        if ($itemTemplate -and $itemTemplate.DescendsFromOrEquals($TemplateId)) {
            $referrer
        }
    }
}
```

```powershell
$baseTemplateId = "{76036F5E-CBCE-46D1-AF0A-4143F9B557AA}"
Get-ItemBasedOnTemplate -TemplateId $baseTemplateId
```

#### Demo

The following demonstrates three base templates:
`Base Template -> Base Template 1 -> Base Template 2`

[image: Query base template]

Interesting discovery. Switched from `Get-Item` to `$db.GetItem()` and the results are considerably faster; SPE wraps objects returned `Get-Item` and `Get-ChildItem` with additional properties.

```powershell
$baseTemplateId = "{3F8A6A5D-7B1A-4566-8CD4-0A50F3030BD8}"
$watch = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
$itemCount = Get-ItemBasedOnTemplate -TemplateId $baseTemplateId | 
    Measure-Object | Select-Object -Expand Count
$watch.Stop()
$time = $watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000
Write-Host "Discovered and returned $($itemCount) items in $($time) seconds"

# Discovered and returned 1307 items in 0.527 seconds
```

Comment: Nice one Mike. Didn't know that existed.

Answer (score 2):

I have done this using the below script. The idea is to go through all the child items of a node to check if the template id of the item matches with template id we are looking for  or inherits from it-

```
$TemplateId = [Sitecore.Data.ID]::Parse("{<your templateId here>}");
$database = "master"
$contentRoot =  Get-Item -Path "/sitecore/content/<your site path here>"
filter Where-InheritsTemplate {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [Sitecore.Data.Items.Item]$item
    )
    if ($item) {
        $itemTemplate = [Sitecore.Data.Managers.TemplateManager]::GetTemplate($item)
        if ($itemTemplate -ne $null -and $itemTemplate.DescendsFromOrEquals($TemplateId)) {
            $Item
        }
    }
}
Get-ChildItem -Path $contentRoot.FullPath | Where-InheritsTemplate
```

Answer (score 1):

I had an additional requirement where addition to finding a specific template, check if the particular field is not null or empty

I extended @vadim Birkos's script and updated a little bit as `$_.Fields["__template"].Value -eq $templateId` wasn't working for me so I used `$_.TemplateId -eq $templateId`

```
$templateId = "{6F6A4612-5750-46CE-97CE-EBDC599FE480}" # Replace with your template ID

# Get all items in the content tree
$items = Get-ChildItem -Path "master:<your content tree>" -Recurse


# Filter the items by template
$itemsUsingTemplate = $items | Where-Object { $_.TemplateId -eq $templateId  -and !([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Fields["SitecoreField"].Value))}

# Output the item paths
$itemsUsingTemplate | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_.Paths.Path }
```

Comment: thank you! Updated part that didn't work for you

Comment: Your welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```
$rootItemId = "{rootItemId }"

$rootItem = Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID $rootItemId

$templateId = "{templateId }"

$query = "fast:$($rootItem.ItemPath)//*[@@templateid='$($templateId)']"

Get-Item -Path "master:" -Query "fast:/sitecore/content/<your site path here>//*[@@templateid='{templateid}']" | Format-Table -Property DisplayName, Id
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all items that are using a specific template in Sitecore using PowerShell, you can use the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet to retrieve all items in the content tree, and then filter the items by checking if they have a `__template field` with the ID of the template.

Here's some example PowerShell code that demonstrates how to do this:

```bash
$templateId = "{12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012}" # Replace with your template ID

# Get all items in the content tree
$items = Get-ChildItem -Path "master:\content\home" -Recurse

# Filter the items by template
$itemsUsingTemplate = $items | Where-Object { $_.TemplateId -eq $templateId  -and !([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Fields["SitecoreField"].Value))}

# Output the item paths
$itemsUsingTemplate | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_.Paths.Path }
```

In this example, we're getting all items in the content tree starting from the home item, and then filtering them by checking if they have a `__template` field with the ID of the template. The filtered items are stored in the $itemsUsingTemplate variable, and then their paths are outputted using the Write-Host cmdlet. You can replace the template ID and the starting path with your own values.

**[Updated]**
Updated because part with condition didn't work.