# How to get ALL specific child-items in a folder using fast query?

Tags: powershell-extensions, powershell

I have here a sample content. Now I want to get all the Article Template under the Folder.

```
Sitecore
    Content
        Folder
            Article1
            Article2
            NewsFolder1
                Article3
                Article4
            NewsFolder2
            Article5
```

I have here a code:

```
$query = "fast:/sitecore/content/Folder/*[@@TemplateID='{76036F5E-CBCE-46D1-AF0A-4143F9B557AA}']" 
$items = Get-Item -Path "master:" -Query $query | Get-ChildItem -rec
$items.Paths.Fullpath
```

But I will only query the first level under Folder (Article1, Article2, and Article5). Can someone advise me how to include in the result the Articles under the NewsFolders?

Comment: Using fast query is not an ideal option. Consider using a different approach like here https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/15168/95.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Micheal West said, using fast query is not a recommended option.
Answer for your question is

`$query = "fast:/sitecore/content/Folder//*[@@TemplateID='{76036F5E-CBCE-46D1-AF0A-4143F9B557AA}']"`

use //* to get the descendants.

Comment: I already tried adding //* but same results. Does it have something to do with the NewsFolder1 template? Because it has a different template. So the code can't go thru its descendants? Please advise

Comment: //* is used to get the descendants. Check the query in https://[Siteurl]/sitecore/shell/default.aspx?xmlcontrol=IDE.XPath.Builder

Comment: It turns out that we need to rebuild the descendants, and  I am now getting the expected results with //*. Thank you.

Comment: @eudaimonia_ That's exactly i did few weeks back to make the fast queries working as expected.. I guess this needs to be added/updated in the answer..

Comment: You mean rebuild links database, right? I've ran into that before as well. And agreed it should be added to the answer.

Comment: @jrap exactly, it has to be added..

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether this is what you need, but i tried to reproduce the scenario in my local
[image]

and using this query i was able to get the fullpaths of all the articles under that folder

```
Get-ChildItem -path "/sitecore/content/Home/Articles Folder" -language * -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.TemplateName -eq 'Article' } | ForEach-Object { $_.Paths.FullPath }
```