# Get all results using Find-Item in sitecore powershell

Tags: powershell-extensions, powershell

I am using Sitecore PowerShell Extension with the below script

```
$indexName = "sitecore_web_index"
$criteria = @(
                @{Filter = "Contains"; Field = "industry_sm"; Value = "{7451A225-6450-4D26-BE04-624FD2E63B76}" },
                @{Filter = "Contains"; Field = "service_sm"; Value = "{0670EE3C-1D07-4172-9ADB-19127D90C180}" }
            )
 $list = Find-Item -Index $indexName -Criteria $criteria | Initialize-Item
```

The issue is above script returns items that follow both filter conditions is it possible to get items even if it follows only one filter condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the below code. I checked a few articles that show that it works with `And` operator, but you can try with `Or` operator.

```
class IndustrySearchResultItem : SearchResultItem
{
   [Sitecore.ContentSearch.IndexField("industry_sm")]
   [string]$Industry
   [Sitecore.ContentSearch.IndexField("service_sm")]
   [string]$Service
}

$props = @{
    Index = "sitecore_master_index"
    Where = "Industry.Contains(@0) Or Service.Contains(@1)"
    WhereValues = "{7451A225-6450-4D26-BE04-624FD2E63B76}", "{0670EE3C-1D07-4172-9ADB-19127D90C180}"
    QueryType = [IndustrySearchResultItem]
}

Find-Item @props
```

Reference: https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/indexing/find-item#where-less-than-string-greater-than

[Powershell get all items that use a template](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/15165/powershell-get-all-items-that-use-a-template)

Hope this helps.